# Model does not train when using Colab Premium GPU

Tags: gpu, classification, google-colaboratory

I recently upgraded my google colab account to premium. But when I select the Premium GPU in runtime [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xeTEr.png) I encounter an issue while trying to train my model. The code runs and it does not show any error but it does not show any progress [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6zePY.png). Only when I change back to normal GPU under runtime the model trains.

Here is the code I am using to set up and train the model

```
model = ClassificationModel('roberta', 'roberta-base', num_labels=3, weight=class_weights.tolist(),
                            use_cuda=True, args={'reprocess_input_data': True, 'overwrite_output_dir': True,
                                                  "num_train_epochs": 10})

model.train_model(train)
```

Comment: Do you have any further information? i have the same issue...

Comment: not yet but it is currently under investigation here: https://github.com/googlecolab/colabtools/issues/3418#issuecomment-1458626331